# PHP - Encrypt and decrypt weird sign

Tags: php, encryption

I am experiencing quite a weird issue with my script. I have this script, that will get posted with jQuery as a POST. This is the URL that gets sent:

```
url: 'index.php?i=v&p=k&token=<?php echo($tokenS); ?>&key=<?php echo $secretKey; ?>&token=<?php echo $tokenS; ?>&time=<?php echo $time; ?>&stime=<?php echo $stime; ?>'
```

When in action, it will look something like this:

```
url: 'index.php?i=v&p=k&token=F53A8D1113D8A158AD89F6A115DCB13174F0E0CC&key=56.50.57.61.106.118.118.114.60.49.49.105.113.113.105.110.103.48.101.113.111.61.51.53.58.56.52.53.56.54.55.53&token=F53A8D1113D8A158AD89F6A115DCB13174F0E0CC&time=15&stime=1386236453'
```

So, the URL contains all sort of information that I need to validate.

My problem comes when I have to validate the `key` variable. I have this:

```
$key = inputFilter($_POST['key']);
            // Need to decrypt the key.
            $key = $this->sDecrypt($_POST['key']);
            /*
             * Need to split the key up..
             * After this, we should have an array looking like this:
             * -> Array ( [0] => ID [1] => URL [2] => TIME) <-
             * ID = id of the advertisement
             * URL = url of the advertisement
             * TIME = time of the advertisment started showing (Should match $stime)
             */
            $key = explode(';',$key);
            $key2 = explode(';',$this->sDecrypt($_SESSION['ad']['key']));
```

Then, after decrypting the key, I am validating it like this:

```
// Check if session key & post key is the same
            if($key[0] != $key2[0] || $key[1] != $key2[1] || $key[2] != $key2[2])
                die("error");
```

And here is where it get's weird. I get the `die("error");` here.

I tried printing out, what the $key contained:

```
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $key[0];
    echo "</pre>";

    echo "<pre>";
    echo $key2[0];
    echo "</pre>";
```

This resulted in this:

```
$key[0] = �
$key2[0] = 608
```

So, the `$key2[0]` have the correct value, but `$key[0]` doesn't. It contain some sort of weir character.

EDIT:

`var_dump( $_POST['key'] );` is `NULL`

Any idea why?

Comment: You are showing the URLs with their GET parameters, and then referencing POST in your code.  Can you `var_dump( $_POST['key'] );` and tell us what that contains.

Comment: Just edited my question. var_dump( $_POST['key'] ); is NULL

Comment: Try looking in $_GET['key'] instead.

Comment: Can you validate (with the developer console for example) that the key is getting POSTed?

Comment: Doh! That worked. Please submit an answer.

Comment: It really looks like your AJAX code isn't POSTing the values as you say it is, but is rather sending them via GET.  When you build up a URL like you describe those parameters will be in the GET array, regardless of what you set the request to.

Comment: I would highly doubt the usefulness of this "encryption", especially after posting the trivial algorithm on a public website. Even without it, most smart people can probably figure it out within a few minutes. FYI: that's not serious security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really looks like your AJAX code isn't POSTing the values as you say it is, but is rather sending them via GET. When you build up a URL like you describe those parameters will be in the GET array, regardless of what you set the request to.

Instead of looking in `$_POST['key']`, try looking in `$_GET['key']`

Or, if you really want, you can swap it for `$_REQUEST`, which will resolve the normal precedence for COOKIE - > GET -> POST

Answer (score 1):

Your variables are sent to your PHP script in the URL, this is a GET method.
However, in your code you are using the POST variables:

```
$key = inputFilter($_POST['key']);
```

And then decode that, which will result in unpredictable, and certainly unwanted behavior.
Change this to:

```
$key = inputFilter($_GET['key']);
```

Comment: Apologies @Borniet for posting what appears to be a duplicate answer, but since I led the questioner to the answer in the comments and was asked to post as an answer I felt I was justified.

Comment: No worries @RobBaillie seems indeed like we both saw the same issue, but indeed, you were also working on it in the comments. You get my upvote!